# How to create a multiple effect textarea like google translate textbox?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jsp, jquery, web

Textbox of google translate (the left textbox- please view my screenshot: http://s970.photobucket.com/albums/ae190/swenteiger7/technology%20screenshot/?action=view&current=google_translate_textbox_event.png) have a lot of nice effects such as automatic highlight a word, automatically scaled ...

I am currently need to create a textarea so in my web application. **I want to know a technology (prefer based on ajax and work well across platforms JSP) or  website tutorials which help me to make a textbox like google translate textarea.**

Thank you for viewing my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get you started see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable and the links at the bottom of that page.

Basically it's not actually a textbox. It's a regular html element, but is marked as editable so people can type into it. But because it's regular html you can do special effects with it.